# de Lubac's Medieval Exegesis online?

Tags: discussion

Question probably self-evident from the title but wondering if anyone knows of an online copy of de Lubac's Medieval Exegesis (in English trans.) Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see the English version online for free anywhere (it is fairly recently published), and the French version (*Exégèse médiévale*) was not freely available on any *legitimate-looking* websites, either.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be only a partial copy of volume 2 of the Jesuit [Henri de Lubac's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_de_Lubac) works on [Medieval Exegesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Exegesis:_The_Four_Senses_of_Scripture) that can be found online. Here is the only partial copy for free of [volume 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ny3yCY8K3IwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=henri%20%20de%20Lubac&lr=&as_brr=3&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false) in English of Medieval Exegesis that I am aware that exists online.